# How can I use C# code inside my Erlang code?

Tags: c#, interface, erlang

I need to use come features implemented in C# into my Erlang code. What interfaces exist to tie Erlang with C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to export C# into un-managed code then use COM interface for example

- [Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx)
- [How to Automate Exporting .NET Function to Unmanaged Programs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16310/How-to-Automate-Exporting-NET-Function-to-Unmanage)

And I'm not sure if there is possible way for mono. By the way I suggest to use ".NET code" instead of "C# code".

*welcome to SO, ymn*